# F# Expected type List but here has type []

Tags: dictionary, asynchronous, f#

I am running my data through this:

```
myData |> List.map(myAsyncMethod) |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

myData is: `MyDataType list` and that is what I am expecting back, but instead I am getting `[]` (which I thought was a list)...

Anyway, I somehow need to convert type [] back into a list, or fix my function to return list... or swap out my datatype to be compatible with [].

Any answer will do, I just need it to work (as efficiently as possible).

Comment: What does the type of `myAsyncMethod` look like? `[]` is an array, which can indeed be a bit confusing, as writing an actual array uses `[|  |]` style brackets.

Comment: That will help. F# needs better error messages and VS support. I will try that when I get back to my computer.   The Async method just runs an update on a value pazsed in.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The error messages are very often not really more than "wrong, fix!", and interpreting them is a matter of experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Async.Parallel` will create an output which is an array.

This makes sense because you need to pre allocate some space to return the result, which you cant do with a list.

You can just use Array.toList to convert to a list at the end

Comment: Thanks, that works. Just changed my data to use an array instead of a list as I assume that will end up being faster than trying to convert it over.